# Technical/legal question about Windows Phone store, on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Would the question below be on-topic or off-topic?

---

An app has appeared on http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ that looks exactly like my open source Android app.

I highly suspect that the publisher took my source code and ported it to Windows Phone, without respecting the license which requires them to publish the modified source code and link it from the app.

What I should do in such a situation?

Comment: Sorry but it is really off topic. But I really encourage you to take the steps row1 quote and send a takedown request.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this would be off-topic. This site deals with questions relating to using Windows Phone and not development.

Microsoft does seem to take this sort of stuff seriously (I know some people who have received take-down requests), so you can fill out a form http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windowsphone/help/jj215905%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

If you don't want to take such serious action, you can 'report a concern' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215906%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It does seem to fall in the middle ground of "I'm not in front of a debugger" (StackOverflow) and "I'm a consumer" (Here), and would ultimately be best handled by your lawyer - and that legal advice is not specific to Windows Phone, so I would see that as off topic.

We *have* had however questions in the past that cover reporting an app that violates the store's terms. But it was asked more from the point of view of "why is this annoying thing happening; anything I can do to stop it", and the [accepted answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/626/106) may help you out in your situation.

Comment: Thanks! In the future this might cover the middle ground: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores

Comment: Software licensing questions are also on-topic at http://programmers.stackexchange.com